# Stored procedure execution in Entity Framework in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am using MVC3 and Entity Framework for calling a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008. The procedure has no parameters and in the profiler I get the proc execution as

```
exec sp_executesql N'sp_GetDashSessionboardRoomTimeSlot', N'@p0 nvarchar(4000)', @p0=NULL
```

This is how I call in the c# code.

```
SqlParameter sa = null;
var query = from dashboardData in TBSCIDBContext.Database.SqlQuery<SessionDashboardData>("sp_GetDashSessionboardRoomTimeSlot", sa)
            select dashboardData;
```

This works fine. But I have changed my database to SQL Server 2005 and I need to use it

So when I call the same procedure using the same C# code the profiler returns the same exec statement but the sql gives error

> Incorrect syntax near 'sp_GetDashSessionboardRoomTimeSlot'

pls help me in how to fix this problem as I need to use this stored procedure and in SQL Server 2005

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. That prefix is reserved by Microsoft for their own use - this incurs a performance penalty and might result in a collision with a Microsoft provided stored procedure in a future release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed it to

var query = from dashboardData in TBSCIDBContext.Database.SqlQuery("sp_GetDashSessionboardRoomTimeSlot")
                        select dashboardData;

it works

Answer (score 0):

Change the `ProviderManifestToken` in SSDL (in your EDMX) to 2005. You probably have it set to 2008.

Comment: Hi I am using entity framework code first. Can you please tell me how to do this change and where should I do this change(as I have not used ef before